# Open new tab pdf in php

Tags: php, pdf

How do I put a link to open a pdf in pdf?

I have a code below which does not work

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
exit;
```

It just shows the link to download and does not generate my file to download.

Comment: $file exists in the same directory as this code?

Comment: So this gives you a PDF to download right?
And what you want is your PDF to open in the Browser, using PDF Plugin if available or whatever the browser has to display it right?